# Refer to a field within a document in buckets_path in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am performing the following elasticsearch query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "stories": "post"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "@timestamp": {
                "order": "asc"
            }
        }
    ],
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "group_by_user_id": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "user_id",
                "size": 50
            },
            "aggs": {
                "posts": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "@timestamp": {
                                    "order": "asc"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "_source": {
                            "excludes": [
                                "@version",
                                "tags",
                                "_traceback",
                                "_exc"
                            ]
                        },
                        "size": 100
                    }
                },
                "min_timestamp": {
                    "min": {
                        "field": "@timestamp"
                    }
                },
                "sort": {
                    "bucket_sort": {
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "min_timestamp": {
                                    "order": "desc"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "size": 50
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My 'post' includes 'user_id', 'message' and '@timestamp' fields in addition to other irrelevant fields.

I would like to filter out all the buckets that their most recent post does not have the message field that matches an input string given by the user - i.e., if a bucket's most recent post has a message field with the value that equals the user's input I would the bucket to be retrieved, otherwise I would like it to be filtered out. How may I accomplish this?

I was thinking about referencing the message field in the top_hits aggregation (something like posts.hits.hits[0]._source.message) in some other aggregation like terms and then use a bucket_selector on the _buckets_count. However, after searching online it seems there is no way to reference these fields within the query. Is there any other way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after struggling with this I finally found a solution that works for me.

I am posting it here if anyone ever encounters a similar issue.

Before the solution, maybe I should also mention that I did not find a way to access a field in a document returned by the top_hits aggregation within the query.

What I did in the end was:

1. use a filter sub aggregation on the posts that were grouped into different
   'groub_by_user_id' buckets which keeps only the posts which have a message field with the specific value.
2. On those posts perform a max aggregation to retrieve the max timestamp amongst the posts that have a matching message in each group.
3. Finally I used bucket_selector to filter out the buckets where the absolute time stamp is not equal to the filtered max timestamp (which means that if there was a message within one of the post in the bucket that had a match it has to be the latest post).
4. Notice the [gap_policy](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline.html#gap-policy) parameter defined to "insert_zeros". Without this the query would have failed since there may be buckets where no post has a message that matches. This parameter will swap a null value with 0 and make the query work.

This is the query that worked for me:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "stories": "post"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "@timestamp": {
                "order": "asc"
            }
        }
    ],
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "group_by_user_id": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "uesr_id",
                "size": 50
            },
            "aggs": {
                "last_post": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "@timestamp": {
                                    "order": "asc"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "_source": {
                            "excludes": [
                                "@version",
                                "tags",
                                "_traceback",
                                "_exc"
                            ]
                        },
                        "size": 1
                    }
                },
                "min_timestamp": {
                    "min": {
                        "field": "@timestamp"
                    }
                },
                "max_timestamp": {
                    "max": {
                        "field": "@timestamp"
                    }
                },
                "msg_filter": {
                    "filter": {
                        "match": {
                            "message": "test"
                        }
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "filter_max_time": {
                            "max": {
                                "field": "@timestamp"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "posts_bucket_filter": {
                    "bucket_selector": {
                        "buckets_path": {
                            "filter_most_recent": "msg_filter>filter_max_time[value]",
                            "most_recent": "max_timestamp[value]"
                        },
                        "gap_policy": "insert_zeros",
                        "script": "params.filter_most_recent == params.most_recent"
                    }
                },
                "stories_bucket_sort": {
                    "bucket_sort": {
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "min_timestamp": {
                                    "order": "desc"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "size": 50
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps someone in the future!